# Do not close ToolStripMenu on clicking in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripmenu

I work on a c# winform project that the main toolstripmenu have not to be hide after user clicks on its item, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Could you make an picture or something? Because as far as I understand it, you can't click on a item from a toolstripmenu that isn't 'opened'. So basically I don't understand.

Comment: @Kilazur I Opened toolstripmenu and click on its items, when I click on a item the toolstriped menu closed automatically. I don't want it hides after clicking.

Comment: Then when you want it to close? and how?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it close when I click on a exit button for example.

Comment: Ok, post the code of what you have. because there is nothing called Toolstripmenu. Which class you're referring to?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel question edited.

Comment: Does that `ToolStripMenuItem` is added to `ToolStrip` or `ContextMenuStrip`? If latter it is easy to do what you're asking.

Comment: Forcing a common UI element to behave in strange ways will only confuse and annoy users.  Reconsider your goal and if you are using the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the AutoClose property of the parent menu item to prevent the menu strip from closing.

To demonstrate:

```
ToolStripMenuItem file = new ToolStripMenuItem("File");
file.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
file.DropDownItems.Add("New");
file.DropDownItems.Add("Open");
file.DropDownItems.Add("Exit");

MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
ms.Items.Add(file);

this.Controls.Add(ms);
```

Now the responsibility is on you to close the menu yourself:

```
file.DropDown.Close();
```

Answer (score 9):

I found better answer on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3739ed18-a316-4181-a660-a5ef2bece807/how-to-disable-menu-hiding-after-menu-item-checked?forum=winforms). Dropdown doesn't close on click, but closes in other cases:

```
DropDown.Closing += new ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler(DropDown_Closing);
...
private void DropDown_Closing(object sender,  ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```